# How to draw matrix with DIA?

Tags: dia

I need to use DIA to draw a matrix. I want a 16x16 matrix where I can edit the text of each box. How can I do this? Is there a pre-defined tool I can use?

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried the "Resizable Grid" object from the "Misc" sheet? Once you've added it to your canvas, open its properties dialog (e.g. double click on it) to configure the number of rows and columns. The grid does not offer text boxes by default, but each cell has a connection point where you can connect text objects.